# How to display a date if entry is only for one day only

Tags: date

I have an entry that has a date. If it starts and ends on the same day, it should only display the day. Like 'September 21, 2013'.

But right now, my code has it like this:

```
<strong>Date:</strong> {entry_date format='%F&nbsp;%j'}&mdash;{expiration_date format='%j'}, {expiration_date format='%Y'}<br />
```

Which pushes out September 21-21, 2013. Is there a way I can modify my code where it would show a single date if the event doesn't stretch over multiple days?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
{entry_date format='%F %j'}{if "{entry_date format='%Y%m%d'}" != "{expiration_date format='%Y%m%d'}"}—{expiration_date format='%j'}{/if}, {expiration_date format='%Y'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be overkill but another option would be something like Encaf's [double date](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/encaf-double-date) which I've found to be handy on a few projects.

Answer (score 0):

Both entry_date and expiration_date are being stored as UNIX timestamp and also output the same if we don't pass the format parameter. So I think, there is no need to format the entry_date and expiration_date while comparison. It would be simple to write:

```
{entry_date format='%F %j'}{if entry_date != expiration_date}—{expiration_date format='%j'}{/if}, {expiration_date format='%Y'}
```